# Javascript Promises: How do you chain results when a javascript remote call is involved?

Tags: javascript, promise

This is more a question of proper syntax. the following code is producing the console log output in the Startup sequence before the remote JavaScript call has been completed. I am a total newbie to promises so I am certain I have the syntax wrong.

Here are the examples of the two segments of relevant code:

```
var getNode = function(sfid,override) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
          var text = "";
          VisJSController.returnObjectsJson(sfid,
            function(result, event) {
              if(event.type === 'exception') {
                console.log("exception");
                console.log(event);
              } else if (event.status) {
                result.Nodes.forEach(function(entry)
                {
                    addNode(entry.id,entry.label,entry.shape,eval(entry.image));
                    if (entry.id != sfid && !(edgeIds.includes(entry.id+sfid) || edgeIds.includes(sfid+entry.id)))
                    {
                        addEdge(sfid,entry.id);
                        console.log('Adding Edge');
                        console.log(sfid);
                        console.log(entry.id);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log('Edge detected');
                        console.log(entry.id);
                        console.log(sfid);
                        console.log(edgeIds);
                    }
                });
                resolve(true);
              } else {
                console.log(event.message);
              }
            }


          );
    });
}

function startup()
{
    getNode('{!SF_ID}',true).then(console.log('finished'));
}
```

In this example I would like to see the finished log to appear at the end after getNode has completed processing the remote request.

Comment: `then(console.log('finished'));` ... `.then` expects a function as an argument. You are supplying the result of calling a function .. `then(() => console.log('finished'));` may do what you want (haven't looked for any issues in the body of the code, that issues was obvious though)

Comment: the other issue is, the only time the promise is resolved is `} else if (event.status) {` ... other cases, the promise remains unresolved - you may want to `reject` in the other conditions?

Comment: Thank you @JaromandaX adding in the syntax for passing the result (even if I don't use it) produces the desired result. When I changed it to getNode('{!SF_ID}',true).then(function(result){console.log('finished')}); all was well.